# hash variable not work in password_verify () php

Tags: php, mysql, password-hash

I hashed my password using `password_hash()`, and verify using `password_verify();`

When i write the hash directly in variable the value be True

```
$hash = '$2y$10$lKwHxxc1YJI01ftNe33pcOvddAVrLd0GHwb3Ya3eqQJ2HxycpHjpO';
```

But When i call the value from MySQL the value be false when i put it in this function , i make echo for the value and the value been true , but i don't know why being false when i put it in `password_verify();`

I look for all previous questions about this problem but i didn't found any answer, this is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])=="Log In") {
    $password = 'aliali12';
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 1");
    $hashed_pass = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    if (password_verify("$password",$hashed_pass['user_pass'])){
        echo "Correct Password";
    }  else {
        echo 'There are some wrong';
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Here is the code that was used to hash the password with:

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['changePassword']); 
$hash = password_hash("$password", PASSWORD_BCRYPT)."\n";
```

Comment: remove the `""` around password variable

Comment: the password is correct i have problem in hash variable

Comment: What is the content of `$hashed_pass['user_pass']`? How did you hash it to begin with? Make sure the length of that column is sufficient (at least 60 chars), otherwise it might be silently failing you due to turnication.

Comment: $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['changePassword']); 
  $hash = password_hash("$password", PASSWORD_BCRYPT)."\n";

Comment: You should never use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on passwords (after hashing, they are safe to store without it, as there are no singlequotes in a hash), and that `\n` might also be the issue here.

Comment: Don't escape your password before you hash it. It shouldn't matter with your example password, but it will lead to problems with passwords containing slashes for example.

Comment: @Qirel is right - don't modify the data before saving it to the database. If you're worried about strings, then use prepared statements (you should do this anyways), so that the data inserted is consistent with how its generated.

Comment: All the code you've shared is wrapped in this strange conditional: `isset($_POST['submit'])=="Log In"`...

Comment: One of your two variables (at least...) is not what you think it is. You should `var_dump()` both `$password` and `$hashed_pass['user_pass']`.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])=="Log In")` that won't work.

Comment: Thaaaaaanks all it's work now when i remover mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: `$hash = trim($hash);` would have gotten rid of the (invisible) trailing linebreak and you wouldn't have needed to change anything, except added that line after the first two that you hashed the password with, yet with the exception of NOT escaping the password. `password_verify()` takes care of security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be two issues here. From [your comment we found that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612975/hash-variable-not-work-in-password-verify-php/43613379#comment74275253_43612975)...

1. You're using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on the password before hashing it. You should never modify passwords before inserting them, keep it clean. This function could possibly change passwords, if they contain for example single-quotes.
2. You have `\n` concated to the hash before inserting it, while comparing, it does not have that. This needs to be removed when hashing the password when this data is being inserted.

These needs to be corrected (the `real_escape()` shouldn't be on passwords, and the newline removed), and the password inserted again after these corrections has been made.

---

In additon to this,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])=="Log In") {
```

isn't what you think it is. It will technically work, as it will compare a boolean to true (so you get `true == true` if its set, `false == true` otherwise). It should simply be

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

---

See [Cleansing User Passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628418/cleansing-user-passwords)

Comment: That's because they used the example in http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php `echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";` - which way too many get caught in that trap. PHP.net should really update that page in regards to inserting into a db. At best; `trim()` would work here for that.

Comment: Then escaping their password where having something like `123'\abc` would be a perfectly valid password, but silently failing later on. That'll be interpreted/changed as `123\'\abc`.

Comment: @Fred *Woah*! I've actually never noticed that in the example. That really shouldn't be in that example, indeed!

Comment: @Qirel I know. Someone I know sent something to the staff at PHP.net about it, but it seems to either have fallen onto deaf ears, or they simply want people to figure it out by themselves. If the latter, I think that's just plain ignorance on their part, should that be the case. Maybe if we sent them more messages about it, that they'll modify the manual in regards to this.

Comment: [*An added note...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612975/hash-variable-not-work-in-password-verify-php#comment74276526_43612975)